# JSqlParser will throw exception when udf function is not defined

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsqlparser

I am using `JSqlParser` to do some simple table name modification, but it will throw exception when I use some udf functions in statements. How to make it ignore function check?

```
def replaceTableName(sql: String) = {
  val select = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql).asInstanceOf[Select]

  val buffer = new java.lang.StringBuilder()
  val expressionDeParser = new ExpressionDeParser() {
    override def visit(tableColumn: Column) = {
      if (tableColumn.getTable.getName != null && tmpTables.contains(resolveName(tableColumn.getTable.getName))) {
        tableColumn.getTable().setName(resolveName(tableColumn.getTable().getName()))
      }
      super.visit(tableColumn)
    }

  }
  val deparser = new SelectDeParser(expressionDeParser, buffer) {
    override def visit(tableName: Table) {
      if(tmpTables.contains(resolveName(tableName.getName)))
        tableName.setName(resolveName(tableName.getName()))
      super.visit(tableName)
    }
  }
  expressionDeParser.setSelectVisitor(deparser)
  expressionDeParser.setBuffer(buffer)
  select.getSelectBody().accept(deparser)
  buffer.toString
}
```

This code will throw

> Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "current_date"  `<K_TIME_KEY_EXPR>`  at line 1, column xx

If my input is `select * from table where date = sub_date(current_date('yyyyMMdd'),'1','yyyyMMdd');`
`sub_date` and `current_date` are my udfs to get yesterday's date.

Comment: Must `mm` (minutes) not be `MM` (month)?

Comment: @JoopEggen not working...

Comment: The problem is CURRENT_DATE like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are special keywords to JSqlParser. These are not allowed as function names and JSqlParser at the moment does not support parameterized K_TIME_KEY_EXPR expressions.

Comment: that's correct! thx @wumpz